# (fixed) using \tkzDefLine create perpendicular line cause error "Missing $ inserted" when using point name with underscore

Tags: tkz-euclide

update: this problem has been fixed in tkz-euclide ver. 4.00.

original post:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(6,0){C}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,5){A_1}
  \tkzDrawPoints(A_1,B,C)
  \tkzDrawPolygon(A_1,B,C)
  \tkzLabelPoints(A_1,B,C)
  
  \tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through A_1](B,C)\tkzGetPoint{a} %no problem for "through A"
  %no problem for parallel option
  %\tkzDefLine[parallel=through A_1](B,C)\tkzGetPoint{a}
  %no problem for other macro
  %\tkzDefPointBy[inversion=center B through A_1](C)\tkzGetPoint{a}
  \tkzDrawSegment(A_1,a)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know there are ways to avoid this, but as this usage don't cause problem for other macro, is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I have some comments of TikZ and tkz-euclide in the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(5,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(4,3.5){A1}
\tkzDrawPoints(A1,B,C)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A1,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints(A1,B,C)
        

%\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through A1] (B,C)    % <<< a blank syntax error
\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through A1](B,C) 
\tkzGetPoint{M} 
\tkzDrawSegment(A1,M)


%\tkzDefLine[parallel=through A1] (B,C)     % <<< a blank syntax error
\tkzDefLine[parallel=through A1](B,C)
\tkzGetPoint{N}
\tkzDrawSegment(A1,N)


%\tkzDefPointBy[inversion=center B through A1] (C)   % <<< a blank syntax error
\tkzDefPointBy[inversion=center B through A1](C)
\tkzGetPoint{P}
\tkzDrawPoint(P)

%\tkzLabelPoints(P)                    % with `s`, it works
%\tkzLabelPoint(P)                    % without `s`, it does not work ^^
\tkzLabelPoint[right](P){$P$}        % without `s`, and label, it works again ^^
%\tkzLabelPoint[right] (P){$P$}        % without `s`, and label, and a blank, it doesnot works again ^^
\end{tikzpicture}

\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
(0,0) coordinate (B) node[below left]{$B$}
(5,0) coordinate (C) node[below right]{$C$}
(4,3.5) coordinate (A) node[above right]{$A$}
($(A)+.3*(C)-.3*(B)$) coordinate (Ar)
($(A)-(C)+(B)$) coordinate (Al)
($(B)!(A)!(C)$) coordinate (H);

\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\draw[red] (Al)--(Ar);
\draw[blue,shorten >=-1cm,shorten <=-1cm] (A)--(H);
\foreach \p in {A,B,C}
\draw[fill=white] (\p) circle(1.5pt);
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Macros with an "s" are used for one or more points so it is always the maths mode that is used and the label is the reference name of the point. Without "s" then a specific label can be given.